# how to hide view block when other view block not giving any search result?

Tags: views, hooks

I have created a view(ABC) in which search criteria: **"country type content"** and other filter is **"promoted to front page"**."Promoted to front page" filtering content using cck boolen field(yes/no).

Another view(XYZ) has search criteria:  **"country type content"** only.

When  promoted to front page cck field is empty or null my first view(ABC) will hide
same as I want to hide second view(XYZ) If first view is hidden.

Both the views i placed at same region **"Header"**.

How to hide (XYZ) view, if (ABC)view has no content or hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such cases, when visiblity of one view need to be dependent on another view, we may ***alter the view***, or we can use ***hook_views_pre_render*** or ***hook_views_pre_render*** to control the view through custom code.

Here as you are **using block**, so you can also use block configuration "***Show block on specific pages***" instead of coding in some custom module.

Then you can select option "***Pages on which this PHP code returns TRUE***" there.

After doing so, you can use the following code in the textarea:

```
<?php

$view = "<Your dependee view's machine name on which other view is dependent>";

$display = "<Your dependee view's display ID>";

$all_row = views_get_view_result($view, $display);

if(count($all_row)>0) {
  return TRUE;
}
?>
```